# Zend Framework 2: get max id considering tablegateway dependancy injection in album application

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I need to know album table max id in controller action. so i write following method in AlbumTable Class. When i call this method in action then it return an empty album model object. I guess that it for `$resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new \Album\Model\Album());` prototype setting in service manager. then i disable `$resultSetPrototype` it return max id as array. Now i am in problem, i can't disable $resultSetPrototype since it is using for data storing and retrieving data in album application and i also required max id for other manipulation. .

How can i get max id considering tablegateway dependency injection.
Here is my method

```
public function getMaxId() {
$select = $this->tableGateway->getSql()->select();
$select->columns(array(
'maxId' => new Expression('MAX(id)')
));

$rowset = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);
$row = $rowset->current();
if (!$row) {
throw new \Exception("Could not retrieve max Id of personal table");
}
return $row;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain better because i don't understand clearly what the problem is. You are calling this method inside the controller and you get an empty object?

Comment: the problem is getMaxId() function return an empty album object not returing max id row due to `$resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new \Album\Model\Album())` settings in service manager config.

Comment: i used your method and it worked fine. Not sure how you can solve that problem

Answer (score 0):

I too tried it from my end and the method `getMaxId()` works.

Try this -

It empty because you must have a property by the name `maxId`in the Album Model Class file.

In Album\Model\Album Class file -

```
class Album {
    public $id;
    .....
    public $maxId;
    ....

    public function exchangeArray($data) {
        $this->id     = (!empty($data['id'])) ? $data['id'] : null;
        .....
        $this->maxId     = (!empty($data['maxId'])) ? $data['maxId'] : 0;
        ....
    }
}
```

This way the `$row` that is returned by your `getMaxId()` method will have a key by the name `maxId`.

Eg:

```
Album\Model\Album Object
(
    ....
    [maxId] => _SOME_VALUE
    ....
)
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem. what you can do to not use the array object prototype for your select is:

```
$query = $this->tableGateway->getSql()->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
$rowset = $query->execute();
...
```

that worked for me